# Cannot access 'java.lang.Object' which is a supertype of... Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies

Tags: android, maven, kotlin, gradle, dependencies

I thought it would be fun and informative to learn more about static code analysis by implementing my own custom linter. I've been trying to declare the below dependencies:

```groovy
dependencies {
    compileOnly "com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:30.1.2"
    compileOnly "com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:30.1.2"
}
```

But Gradle is giving an error that these dependencies cannot be resolved. After digging some, I found that MavenCentral and Google have seemingly different versioning for these libraries, with Google being the version described in the code snippet above and MavenCentral having version 25.3.0 as the latest version. If I swap out the version numbers for those [described on MavenCentral](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.lint/lint-api), the dependencies can be resolved by Gradle but my custom linter code is completely highlighted in red and gives an error

```
Cannot access 'java.lang.Object' which is a supertype of my_custom_linter. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
```

There are *many* SO posts regarding this error, and the few that have been resolved were resolved by using the most recent version of an available dependency, which in my case circles back to the first error described in this post.

---

Project level `build.gradle`:

```groovy
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.6.10' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Lint module `build.gradle`:

```groovy
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm'
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.10"
    compileOnly "com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:25.3.0"
    compileOnly "com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:25.3.0"
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes("Lint-Registry": "com.example.lint_checks.LintRegistry")
    }
}
```

App module `build.gradle`:

```groovy
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        ...
    }

    buildTypes {
        ...
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.7'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {
    lintChecks project(path: ":lint-checks")
    ...
}
```

`settings.gradle`

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "Custom Linter"
include ':app'
include ':lint-checks'
```

`InputTypeDetector.kt` (custom lint class):

```kotlin
/* Entire class highlighted by IDE with error message: 
Cannot access 'java.lang.Object' which is a supertype of 'com.example.lint_checks.InputTypeDetector'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies */ 

class InputTypeDetector: LayoutDetector() {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        internal val ISSUE_MISSING_INPUT_TYPE = Issue.create(
            id = "MissingInputType",
            briefDescription = "Specify inputType attribute to get proper keyboard shown by system.",
            explanation = "You should specify an inputType for each EditText so that you can get the proper keyboard to be shown by system.",
            category = Category.USABILITY,
            priority = 8,
            severity = Severity.ERROR,
            implementation = Implementation(
                InputTypeDetector::class.java,
                Scope.ALL_RESOURCES_SCOPE
            )
        ).addMoreInfo("https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style")
    }

    override fun getApplicableElements(): Collection<String>? {
        return listOf(
            SdkConstants.EDIT_TEXT,
            "androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText",
            "android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText"
        )
    }

    override fun visitElement(context: XmlContext, element: CoroutineContext.Element) {
        if (!element.hasAttribute(SdkConstants.ATTR_INPUT_TYPE)) { // Check if the element has the `android:inputType` attribute
            context.report(
                issue = ISSUE_MISSING_INPUT_TYPE, // The issue that we defined above
                location = context.getLocation(element),
                message = ISSUE_MISSING_INPUT_TYPE.getExplanation(TextFormat.TEXT)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
I've verified the `lint-api` and `lint-checks` jar files are in the external libraries directory of my project. Gradle has resolved and downloaded these dependencies when requesting version 25.3.0. Why am I getting the error about accessing `java.lang.Object` and checking my classpath?

I have been following this [tutorial](https://varunbarad.com/blog/write-custom-android-lint-rule-layout-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s not clear to me, which dependency resolution repositories you have configured as you don’t provide your `settings.gradle` file. So I’ll assume that you have configured the following there:

```groovy
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Now, while version 25.3.0 of `lint-api` and `lint-checks` exists, it has dependency declarations that make it unsuitable for being used as a compile-time dependency. So I’ve upgraded the version to 26.6.4:

```groovy
    compileOnly "com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:26.6.4"
    compileOnly "com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:26.6.4"
```

That brings in all required dependencies. But there was still one issue with your `InputTypeDetector` implementation: the `visitElement` method signature is wrong in that it uses `CoroutineContext.Element` as the type of `element`. It should be `org.w3c.dom.Element`, though:

```kotlin
    override fun visitElement(context: XmlContext, element: org.w3c.dom.Element) {
        // …
    }
```

With these changes, I could successfully build your `lint-checks` project (tested with Gradle 7.4.2).

---

Responding to your comment: I’m afraid, I can’t reproduce the error with [your code](https://github.com/harr1424/CustomLinter). Note, however, that I made a few modifications that might make a difference:

- I had to add a missing import in `LintRegistry.kt`:
  `import com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.CURRENT_API`
- I have removed `.idea/` before importing your project into Android Studio.
- For security reasons, I have removed the `gradle/`, `gradlew` and `gradlew.bat` files. Then I added a fresh Gradle Wrapper of the same version (7.4.2).

Could you maybe try to do the same and import the project afresh to see if that maybe fixes it? Another thing worth trying to rule out issues with Android Studio: see if building from the command line works, e.g., with `./gradlew lint-checks:build`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to review and provide a solution. My `settings.gradle` file was as you assumed. Unfortunately, upgrading the lint dependencies to version 26.6.4 did not resolve the issue. If you would like to see all of my project code, I have hosted it at https://github.com/harr1424/CustomLinter

Comment: I have updated my answer. Just wondering: what exact error do you get now, still the `Cannot access 'java.lang.Object'` one?

Comment: That is correct, I have followed the most recent steps you have described and I still receive the error `Cannot access 'java.lang.Object`

Comment: Weird :-(  Did building from the command line fail, too?

Comment: Despite re-attempting the steps you provided, invalidating cache, and restarting Android Studio, I was not able to avoid the error responsible for this post and bounty. I've now instead cloned the code to a different computer and attempted to build, and it works as expected! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for awarding the bounty. Have you maybe already found the difference between the two computers that causes this error? If you should find the cause, I’d be interested to hear about that :-)

Comment: The computer I could not resolve the error (and still cannot) is a machine running Mac OS Monterey, and the computer on which the error no longer appeared is running Manjaro Linux. Both computers have the same version of Android Studio 2021.1.1 Patch 2. One thing I noticed on the Mac is an error `Kotlin version that is used for building with Gradle (1.6.10) differs from the one bundled into the IDE plugin (1.6.20)` but changing to the Kotlin version bundled with the IDE (1.6.20) results in the error `Plugin version (1.6.20) is not the same as library version (1.3.71) `

Comment: Here changing the gradle plugin version in project and module level `build.gradle` files to 1.3.71 and syncing still results in an error `Plugin version (1.6.10) is not the same as library version (1.3.71) ` but on the Linux machine after making this change, all error messages disappeared and I could run `./gradle lint` no problem. I am not certain what, but I believe the problem involves the gradle plugin not changing as specified on the Mac version of Android Studio.

Comment: You might find that you don't have to go to another computer.  I can't afford the luxury, so I manage to go back to an old copy of my source tree, and can then apply the same changes I made before.  This does not break things ... until it does.,

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR: It is a bug for certain versions of Android Studio. Do an upgrade.**

I had the whole code becoming underlined with red (showing the error) in several projects, in every build.gradle.kts file, for seemingly no reason as this exact code used to work fine just a couple of days before.

What I've found out was that ***it was caused by a bug in Android Studio itself.***

And I actually found it being reported on some forum.

To store IDEs I use Jetbrains Toolbox.
I used to use Android Studio Flamingo 2022.2.1 Patch 2, but it also could have been that the Toolbox automatically upgraded AS to this version behind the scenes, bringing the bug.

It could have been caused by IDE corruption of some sort, so it might help to just reinstall your IDE (you can keep your settings).

**For me the bug was resolved by deleting the old and installing a newer version of Android Studio, Giraffe 2022.3.1 RC 1.**